# How to export VRM in three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

Hope you are feeling good today!

I have a vrm file that has mtoon material and imported it to the three.js project using VRM loader.
But I faced missing material issues when I exported model using gltf exporter.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { GLTFExporter} from "three/examples/jsm/exporters/GLTFExporter";
import Exporter from 'three-gltf-exporter';
import { OBJExporter } from "three/examples/jsm/exporters/OBJExporter";
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader";
import { VRMLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/VRMLoader";
import { VRM } from "@pixiv/three-vrm";



async function download(
  model: any,
  fileName: any,
  format: any,
  screenshot: any
) {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    function save(blob, filename) {
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
    }

    function saveString(text, filename) {
        save(new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain" }), filename);
    }

    function saveArrayBuffer(buffer, filename) {
        console.log("buffer",buffer)
        save(new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), filename);
    }

    // Specifying the name of the downloadable model
    const downloadFileName = `${
        fileName && fileName !== "" ? fileName : "CharacterCreatorModel"
    }`;

    if (format && format === "gltf/glb") {
        const exporter = new Exporter();
        var options = {
        trs: false,
        onlyVisible: false,
        truncateDrawRange: true,
        binary: true,
        forcePowerOfTwoTextures: false,
        maxTextureSize: 1024 || Infinity,
        };
        exporter.parse(
        model.scene,
        function (result) {
            if (result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            console.log(result);
            saveArrayBuffer(result, `${downloadFileName}.glb`);
            } else {
            var output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
            console.log(output);
            saveString(output, `${downloadFileName}.gltf`);
            }
        },
        options
        );
    } else if (format && format === "obj") {
        const exporter = new OBJExporter();
        saveArrayBuffer(exporter.parse(model.scene), `${downloadFileName}.obj`);
    } else if (format && format === "vrm") {
        var vrmScene;
        model.userData.gltfExtensions = { VRM: {} };
        console.log("VRM ModelAAAAAA: ", model);
        await VRM.from(model).then((vrm) => {
          vrmScene = vrm.scene;
          vrmScene.userData.gltfExtensions = { VRM: {} };

          console.log(vrmScene)
        // var result = JSON.stringify(vrm);
        // saveString(result, `${downloadFileName}.vrm`);
        });

        const exporter = new Exporter();
        var options = {
          trs: false,
          onlyVisible: true,
          truncateDrawRange: true,
          binary: true,
          forcePowerOfTwoTextures: false,
          maxTextureSize: 1024 || Infinity,
        };
        exporter.parse(
          vrmScene,
          function (result) {
              var output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
              // saveString(output, `${downloadFileName}.vrm`);
              console.log(result)
              saveArrayBuffer(result, `${downloadFileName}.vrm`);
          },
          options
        );

  }
}
```

This is a screenshot of exported model.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRmiq.jpg)

How can I fix that? Or there are any other solution for exporting vrm in three.js?

Any solutions are welcome!
Thanks in advance!‍♀️

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This feels really specific to this particular format and / or loader. To be clear `console.log(vrm)` is what is creating this output? It looks like something got converted to string that shouldn't have been. You really may get the most mileage by posting in the VRM repo.